# What database should I use locally if I'm going to use Aurora Serverless?

Tags: docker, amazon-rds-aurora

I'm planning to use Aurora Serverless in QA/PROD and then a docker container for running a compatible engine locally. Should I use MariaDB 10.0 or MySQL 5.6?

Database *need* is low, we're not doing anything crazy. We're developing a Java (Spring Boot, Hibernate) and choose to go with a relational database. We choose to go with a MySQL driver because that's the DB we're familiar with, but not a DBA and so therefore we're scratching the surface.

We want to have locally running version of the database rather than being dependent on a connection back up to AWS while working. We're small enough where we don't have a direct connect and managing the DB security of people being able to work anywhere/anytime isn't something we feel we can keep up with.

Also, if this is a bad idea please speak up - thanks!

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information as what your business needs for the database will drive which database software you use. As for it being a good or bad idea that will also depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Since Amazon claim that Aurora Serverless is compatible with MySQL 5.6, why do you think MariaDB 10.0 is a good choice for the development environment?

Comment: How's being owned by Oralce factor into your development process? Also, why not use Aurora Serverless for development as well, since it costs you less than a cup of coffee per day? By the way, you have a logical flaw in your compatibility reasoning. The fact that MariaDB and Aurora are both compatible with MySQL 5.6 does not mean that they are compatible with each other.

Comment: Because it's not owned by Oracle - And MariaDB 10.0 is also MySQL 5.6 compatible.

Comment: I updated details in the original question as attempting to have a conversation in comments is _rough_

Comment: when you go through the Create Database guide in the AWS Console if you select MariaDB the recommended option is Amazon Aurora, same is true for MySQL